# ScrollView isnt scrolling

Tags: android-studio, android-scrollview

Here is my code:
'

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="5000dp"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

'
When I test my app the and try to scroll its standing At the same position and not scrolling.

Comment: You need to add views inside `LinearLayout` till out of the screen

Comment: I already did it

Comment: Make your `ScrollView` match_parent